# Keeping a "static-sized" div centered when resizing page

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a width of 465px, and I want to keep it centered when the page is resized. I can't manage to really center it when using a set width rather than using a %.

Example: I had used "margin-left: 40%;" but when the screen is small, the div gets pushed too far to the right (because it doesn't shrink with the screen), and when the page is full screen the div sits too far left.

Comment: Need to know the structure of your HTML page.  Is the body centered, or are you asking how to center all of the content in general?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; // Position 50%
    top: 50%;
    width: 465px;
    height: 465px;
    margin: -232px 0 0 -232px; // - ( width / 2 ) to center and height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a width set, simply use this in your `CSS` for consistent horizontal centering.

```
.name-of-div {
  width:465px;
  margin:auto auto;
}
```

Further.. if you would like it centered both horizontally *and* vertically take a look at this page which demonstrates the following `CSS`

```
.name-of-div {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Answer (score 0):

also this should work `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: he didn't even put the code what can we do, but thanks for clarification